# Indirect modification of overloaded element has no effect

Tags: php, eloquent

I have the following Eloquent query:

```
$item = Item::where('sku', $sku)->first();
```

After this query comes in I'm adding a variety of elements manually such as:

```
$item['total'] = $item['subtotal'] + $this->currentInventory();
```

Statements like the above that modify the object work just fine.

It stops working when I do the following:

```
$item['fields'] = [];

$fields = DB::table('item_fields')->where('item_id', $item['id'])->get();

foreach ($fields as $f) {
    if (!isset($item['fields'][$f->field_group_name]))
         $item['fields'][$f->field_group_name] = [];

    $item['fields'][$f->field_group_name]['valid_values'] = DB::table('item_field_valid_values')->where('item_field_id', $f->item_field_id);
}
```

This will cause the line `$item['fields'][$f->field_group_name] = [];` to produce the error:

```
Indirect modification of overloaded element of Item has no effect
```

How can it be that I can assign `$item['fields'] = []` but when I try to add an actual element to the `$item['fields']` array that I get this error?

PHP version 5.6.0.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First off, you're missing `get()` in your code, so either:

**1** You are iterating over the `Query\Builder` instead of the array of results, because you never executed the query. (I suppose you forgot it only here, because otherwise you would probably get `trying to get property of non-object`)

or **2** one of the rows has `''` or `null` value in the `field_group_name` column.

That's why your code does this:

```
$item['fields'][NULL] = [];
```

and that's causing `Indirect modification ...` error.

So add check for empty value first:

```
if ($f->field_group_name && ! isset($item['fields'][$f->field_group_name]))
     $item['fields'][$f->field_group_name] = [];
```

you may need to adjust it to your needs, but you get the idea.

Comment: Yes, I left out the `get()` on this post. Fixed. Added a check, but non-empty values still produce this error.

Comment: I did notice that if I switch to filling another variable with the field data (such as `$fields`) and then do `$item['fields'] = $fields;` after the loop completes then that works fine. This is the workaround I had to do, but I'm still baffled why this would be necessary in the first place.

Comment: That may be it. Seems to fit the workaround I had to do. Good detective work!